# handle api exception with bloc cubit flutter

Tags: flutter, api, error-handling, state-management, flutter-bloc

how to  catch same error in all cubits at once and send it to ui the same code... i want for example wherever server return to me invalid login in api layer send it to bloc layer to clear local storage and send state to ui in order to pop and navigate to login screen
so how to inform all blocs with this event at once or how to inform inform auth bloc from all my apis at once like catching same error from all apis and trigger delete event to auth bloc..
I'm using flutter_bloc /http or dio

Answer (score 0):

after a whole time... now for anyone see this question it's solved using dio interceptors like creating a response interceptor and check specific response code like 403 after that trigger an bloc event to logout along with define this bloc as a top level bloc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).